Find a way to prevent or detect screen recording in my Android app
I'm building an app that broadcasts LIVE using AWS IVS.
In order to respond to customer requests, screen recording must be prevented to a minimum.
We want to limit screen recording within the device, not through hacking or external camera recording.
Basically, the method below was used.
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
However, the screen is black but the audio is being recorded.
I would like to use a way to prevent audio from being recorded or to turn off the audio if it can detect that the screen is currently being recorded.
Below is a method that could not be used because the conditions were not met:

How to detect if another process is using Mic after attempting to record using MediaRecorder


Asking the user for AUDIO_RECORD permission cannot be used because it can make the user too scared.


How to determine that recording is in progress by looking at the status of the displayID added in DisplayManager.


If you start recording before running the app, you will not be able to get the event where displayId is added.


Detect capture using DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE permission


API level 34 is too high, it detects screen capture but not screen recording.

I would like to know if there are any other ways.
